# Gridview get next and previous cells values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to get a `gridview` row previous and next cell value on `rowdatabound` event.  I tried this

```
GridViewRow prevRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];
Label previousValue = prevRow.FindControl("SLNO") as Label;
```

But it throws an error like this

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Thanks

Comment: It's because there is no row with the index of `e.Row.RowIndex - 1` in `Rows`, so you face this error. Check the value of `e.Row.RowIndex - 1` and length of `Rows`.

Comment: It throws an error when I use e.Row.RowIndex + 1 also.

Comment: check your `Rows` and see how many rows you have in it ?! and check the value of passed `e.Row.RowIndex`, too. and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the

```
GridView1.Rows.Count > 0
```

And then be sure that you start the `rowdatabound` from the second row, otherwise it will always throw an error `Out Of Range`, because it goes to the first row and it can not find a previous one.

Comment: It throws the same error when I check for rows count also.

Answer (score 0):

Try below block of code to resolve your issue.

Previous:

```
  if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridViewRow prevRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex > 0 ?   e.Row.RowIndex - 1 : e.Row.RowIndex];
                    Label previousValue = prevRow.FindControl("SLNO") as Label;
                }
```

Next:

```
if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridViewRow prevRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Row.Count - 1 != e.Row.RowIndex ?   e.Row.RowIndex + 1 : e.Row.RowIndex];
                        Label previousValue = prevRow.FindControl("SLNO") as Label;
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works perfect.  Why I am asking this query means, I have to change the background color of the gridview row if I have the same value in the current and previous row cell value, when I move the mouse over any one of the row.

Comment: Glad it help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblCurrentValue = (e.Row.FindControl("SLNO") as Label);//Here you will get your current row..

        GridViewRow PreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];
        if(PreviousRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Here you will get the PreviousRow 
            Label lblPreviousValue = PreviousRow.Cells[2].FindControl("SLNO") as Label;//You need to specify the cell
        }

    }
}
```

Same way you can get the next cells value....like this..

```
            GridViewRow NextRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex + 1];
            if(NextRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
              Label lblNextValue = NextRow.Cells[2].FindControl("SLNO") as Label;//You need to specify the cell
            }
```